# Parametrizing motion of string around rod

Tags: calculus, parametric

I'm trying to solve this problem with calculus.

A string is wound symmetrically around a circular rod. The string goes exactly 4 times around the rod. The circumference of the rod is 4 cm. and its length is 12 cm. Find the length of the string.

My parametrization is

$r(t)=\left(t, \frac{2}{\pi}\cos(t),\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(t)\right)$.

When I compute the integral

$\int_0^{12} \sqrt{1+(-\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(t))^2+(\frac{2}{\pi}\cos(t))^2}$,

my answer does not match the correct answer (20 cm). I suspect the problem is with the period of the trig functions, but I do not know what has to be done with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $r(t)$ moves by $2\pi$ in the $x$ direction per turn, whereas it should move by $3$, i.e. the $x$ component should be $3t/(2\pi)$, and the upper integration limit should then be $8\pi$. Alternatively, you could make the argument of the trigonometric functions $2\pi t/3$ (without changing the upper integration limit).

That makes the result come out right, but there's a much easier way to do this: A cylinder is a [developable surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface), so you can just unroll it as a plane and calculate the length of the string by Pythagoras as

$$
\sqrt{(12\,\text{cm})^2+(4\cdot4\,\text{cm})^2}=20\,\text{cm}\;.
$$

Comment: I understand the first substitution, but how do you defend the substitution with $2\pi t/3$?

Comment: @Moz: The ratio between the rate at which the trigonometric argument changes and the rate at which $x$ changes has to be $2\pi/3$; it doesn't matter which of the two you call $t$, expect in the integration limits. I added this variant because it fit your integration limits, so I figured that this was perhaps your intended meaning of $t$. (By the way, your integral is missing the $\mathrm dt$.)